# Using an entire eclipse project in py4j

Tags: java, python, py4j

I have a bunch of Java code in an eclipse project folder that I'd like to be able to use in python development using py4j.

Is there any canonical way to connect the Java project to python 3.0 (anaconda)? So far, my understanding is that I'd have to create an entry point for every class in the project, then create a

```
 GatewayServer gatewayServer = new GatewayServer(new DateRangeEntryPoint());
 gatewayServer.start();
 System.out.println("Gateway Server Started");
```

Somewhere in the main part of the Java project.

Comment: Also, please know that when it come to Java and Eclipse, I have very little idea what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one GatewayServer in your Java project. Entry points are optional and only needed if you want to manage state on the Java side, for example, share an instance between multiple Python interpreters. You can always call constructors on the Python side.

For example, from Python, you could do this without an entry point:

```
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
gateway = JavaGateway()
date_range = gateway.jvm.your.package.DateRange()
date_range.someMethod()
```

Comment: On the java side, would I just use:

 `GatewayServer gatewayServer = new GatewayServer();
 gatewayServer.start();
 System.out.println("Gateway Server Started");`